# Как получить значение backgroundPosition?

Tags: css, javascript

Здравствуйте, мне необходимо получить значение `obj.style.backgroundPosition`.
Возможно ли это вообще?

Или как получить css свойства left и top обьекта div абсолютно спозиционированного?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('div#hai')).backgroundPosition`

[пруф](http://jsfiddle.net/bugmenot/Gtyhf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("elementID").style.backgroundPosition
```

Comment: Кэп.
Это ничего не возвращает, а мне нужно чтобы вернуло именно значение даного свойства причём желательно по отдельности left и top ... хотя это я уже загнул))